# How to access a IBAction from a SKView?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiview, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I am making a little game with few mini games. On the 1.VC I have UIButtons inside a scrollView to choose the mini game. When the miniGame is loaded (a UIVC) it loads a SKView with the chosen SKScene game.
This is my App view Setup:

```
1.
    UIViewController -> 1.1. ScrollView -> 1.1.1. UIButton -> 1.1.1.1. UIViewController -> 1.1.1.1.1. SKView -> 1.1.1.1.1.1. SKScene (the 1. mini game).
    In the 1.1.1.1. VC I have a backButton (UIButton) which returns me back to the 1.VC. 
    Since I added the backButton in 1.1.1.1.VC I can always return at any moment in the first mini game to 1.VC.
```

PROBLEM:
The only way to go back from 1.1.1.1. (or any deeper) to 1. is by clicking the UIButton. I want to go back programmatically. When the endGameVC (a SKScene) is presented I want it to "seque" or "present" back to the 1.VC automatically (using a NSTimer).

So far I have tried:

1.

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Result:
Black Screen - cant do anything from here

2.

```
[self.view presentScene:nil];
```

Result:Gray screen - I removed the skview and could go back with the button click

3.

```
 [self.view removeFromSuperview];
 [self.view addSubview:[[WBMGamesDataManager sharedInstance] tempy]];
```

Result:

```
-[WBMMainVC superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ac4c30
2014-04-04 11:54:06.317 KinderApp[1940:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WBMMainVC superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9ac4c30'
```

... other stuff that I tried didn't get me anywhere.

Any idea or solution is welcome. If you know what I am doing wrong, or if the whole approach is fishy I am open for comments/critics. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

In my:

```
@implementation MiniGameConcept
```

which is a `SKScene` I have put the following line of code at the place where I used my timer/counter where I needed the game to end:

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This leads me to the 1. VC which is my main screen where the player can choose the mini game set.

It worked for me. I also found a way to go one step back, but this basically gets me to the rootVC. Console output with NSLog shows the VC name.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using segues on way of doing this is by popping the current view controller

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

but for this to work you need to call it from the UIViewController that hosts the SKView so depending on where you need to go back programatically, pass a reference of the UIViewController to that desired view, and create a method that will simply invoke the above line

```
/////in UIViewController
-(void)popIt{
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

////in the view where you want to simulate the back method
[referenceToVC popIt];
```

hope this helps, feel free to ask if you anything is unclear.